# A small printf-like function using variadic templates

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic

I'm looking to get some feedback on a small `printf`-like function I wrote that provides simplified behavior similar to `boost::format`:

```
#ifndef EXT_FORMAT_HPP__
#define EXT_FORMAT_HPP__
// ext::format
// Implements a variadic printf-like function providing behavior similar to
// boost::format
#include <regex>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <utility>

namespace {

inline std::string format_helper(
    const std::string &string_to_update, 
    const size_t) {
  return string_to_update;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
inline std::string format_helper(
    const std::string &string_to_update, 
    const size_t index_to_replace, 
    T &&val,
    Args &&...args) {  
  std::regex pattern{"%" + std::to_string(index_to_replace)};
  std::string replacement_string{(std::ostringstream{} << val).str()};
  return format_helper(
      std::regex_replace(string_to_update, pattern, replacement_string), 
      index_to_replace + 1, 
      std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

} // namespace


namespace ext {

template <typename... Args>
inline std::string format(const std::string &format_string, Args &&...args) {
  return format_helper(format_string, 1, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

} // namespace ext

#endif
```

Usage example:

```
#include "format.hpp"
#include <iostream>

struct foo {
  int value;
  foo(int val) : value{val} {
  }
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const foo &f) {
  os << "foo(" << f.value << ")";
  return os;
}

int main() {
  double tmp = 37.382;
  std::cout << ext::format("%1 + %2 * %1 = %3", 5, tmp, 5 + tmp * 5) << std::endl;

  // Support user defined types provided the appropriate operator<< overload is defined.
  foo a_foo(55);
  std::cout << ext::format("Here is a foo constructed with 55: %1", a_foo) << std::endl;
};
```

This is not written to replace `boost::format`; it's intended to be used as a header-only include with a very limited scope. As currently written, it is possible to supply too few or too many arguments to the parameter pack. Passing too few arguments will return a string that still has format specifiers. Passing excess arguments are simply ignored and you pay the price of excess calls to `std::regex_replace`, which will do nothing. With that in mind, I'm looking for any and all feedback.

Comment: I made some changes that hopefully makes the code easier to read. I refactored `format_helper` for clarity rather than trying to squeeze everything into the return call. I also renamed variables to be more descriptive and reduced all line lengths to be within 80 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find this to be a sweet demo, but I don't like the traps in it for the unwary. Like you mention, there is little validation of parameter counts. There is also a chance that the same location can be replaced multiple times, e.g. with a call to `ext::format("%1", "%2", "%3, "%4", "hi!")` resulting in `"hi!"`. Perhaps you might consider that a bonus.

What I find most surprising in the code is this:

> ```
> std::string replacement_string{(std::ostringstream{} << val).str()};
> ```

I would probably have tended towards `auto replacement_string{std::to_string(val)};` or, more likely, just embedded that in the call to `regex_replace`. Do you do this for compatibility with existing code that provides an overload for `operator<<` but not `to_string`?

Finally, I'm torn about the use of `regex`. It seems like a pretty big hammer without a lot of need, here, however it does keep the code short and sweet, and implicitly avoids an infinite loop that a flawed implementation might have with `ext::format("%1", "%1")`.

Reviewing the tests, I find the `Does_Not_Alter_Format_String` test to be surprising as well. I would have thought the `const` qualifier would indicate this well enough.

Comment: I didn't know about `std::to_string` overloading! I did it primarily to support any class that overloads `operator<<`. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: I believe it would be possible to just call `to_string(val)`, and provide a template `ext::to_string()` that uses `<<`, for those classes without their own `to_string()`.

Answer (score 0):

### FTBFS

This code doesn't compile here (GCC 9.2, -std=c++2a):

```
29935.cpp:24:64: error: ‘class std::basic_ostream<char>’ has no member named ‘str’
   24 |   std::string replacement_string{(std::ostringstream{} << val).str()};
      |                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
```

I had to expand that to keep a reference to the concrete class:

```
  std::ostringstream stream{};
  stream << val;
  std::string replacement_string{stream.str()};
```

### Major

We can pass `%%` to `std::sprintf()` to produce a single `%%`, but that doesn't work here, so there's no way for the format string to specify a literal `%1` to output.

### Very minor

There's a stray `;` after the definition of `main()` in the test program.